# Jquery - Construct a file name to load, using member's name from list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently use Jquery to do the following. When you hover over a list item (member's listing) and click the review tab, the member's review page is loaded. With this setup, each list item has to have its own specific code, requiring more id tags and... manually entering the file name for the review page. I've been working on a code that is more general...one that constructs the file name to load on click.

I need the code to combine the folder name (which is the same for all review pages) with the first and last name of the selected member (folder/lastName,firstName.php). Forgive me for not knowing proper terms... I'm learning on my own:/ So far, this is what I have for the code. It does everything except load the file...

```
$('li.services').each(function(){
$('.proviewtab').click(function(e){ 

  var name = $(this).find("p2").text(); 
  name = name.split(" ", 2); 
  var firstName = name[0]; 
  var lastName = name[1]; 
  var folder = "reviews-pest-control-va"; 
  var reviewsPath = folder + '/' + lastName + ',' + firstName + '.php'; 
  reviewsFile = reviewsPath.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase(); 

  e.preventDefault(); 
  $('#insert').empty(); 
  $('#insert').load(reviewsFile); 
  $('.lbox').removeClass('hbox'); 
  $('.lbox').addClass('tempbox'); 
  $('.mainflipper').addClass('top'); 
}); 
});
```

Here's the html. I'm trying to combine the folder name, last and first name for use with the load command.

```
<li class="services amelia chesterfield powhatan richmond sussex nottoway 
   greensville bugs bedbugs rodents bees reptiles">
    <div class="lpic">
    <div class="lbox hbox">
    <div class="prolight"></div>
    <div class="pro"><img src="http://integritycontractingofva.com/image/KimMedina.jpg" />
    <p2>Kim Medina<br/>
    (804) 381-8026<br />
    Dodson Pest Control</p2>
    <div class="proviewtab"><p3>Reviews</p3></div></div></div></div>
</li>
```

My test page using the above code and html http://integritycontractingofva.com/testpage.php

Here's a page on my site using my current code and html. It may give a better idea of what I'm trying to replicate. http://integritycontractingofva.com/Pest-Control-in-Chesterfield%2C-VA---Midlothian%2C-VA---Chester%2C-VA---Moseley%2C-VA.php

Thanks in advance for any help :^)

**Edit** I got it to work. When the "Reviews" button is clicked, the appropriate (closest) first and last name are combined to create the file name, which then loads.

The html

```
<li class="services amelia chesterfield powhatan richmond sussex nottoway 
       greensville bugs bedbugs rodents bees reptiles">
        <div class="lpic">
        <div class="lbox hbox">
        <div class="pro"><img src="http://integritycontractingofva.com/image/KimMedina.jpg" />
        <p>Kim Medina<br/>
        (804) 381-8026<br />
        Dodson Pest Control</p>
        <div class="proviewtab"><p3>Reviews</p3></div></div></div></div>
    </li>
```

The code

```
$('.proviewtab').click(function(e){  
 var name = $(this).closest(".pro").find("p").text();
 name = name.split(/^(\w+)\s+(\w+)/);
 var firstName = name[1]; 
 var lastName = name[2];
 var folder = "reviews-pest-control-va";  
 var reviewsPath = folder + '/' + lastName + ',' + firstName + '.php';
 reviewsFile = reviewsPath.toLowerCase();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#insert').empty();
    $('#insert').load(reviewsFile);
    $('.lbox').removeClass('hbox');
    $('.lbox').addClass('tempbox');
    $('.mainflipper').addClass('top');
```

});

Comment: It's working on both pages here. Maybe you shouldn't be replacing the blank spaces on the URL, and instead just encoding them?

Comment: @MelanciaUK I initially added the regex to remove spaces, because I had no idea if the split would include/remove them. Turns out the spaces weren't the problem. Thank you for taking the time to reply:)